# String format with a negative timespan

Tags: c#, string, timespan

I have an issue with a string format with a timespan.

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes)
```

Which produce this result **12:08** but the problem is that it can go in minus then it look like this **-01:-59** which is not correct it should look like this **-01:59**. 
I have tried to use the Math.Abs, but it will just show a 0 even if the number is -56
What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Take a look: [Formatting a negative TimeSpan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223902/formatting-a-negative-timespan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Math.Abs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs.aspx):

```
string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", Math.Floor((decimal)ts.Hours), Math.Abs(ts.Minutes))
```

Examples:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(-1, -1, 0); // returns -01:01

ts = new TimeSpan(-1, 1, 0); // returns -00:59

ts = new TimeSpan(1, 1, 0); // returns 01:01
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add this. I have try to use this. But it will only show 0 even if it shows -57. And i still need to show the minut.

Comment: @mortenstarck: need more help?